# return a promise from inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, winjs

I have a recursive function and I am trying to make it run in sequence, returning the promise every time.
The code is recursive and works well but works only for the first item in the for loop.

Example:

- folder: 1   -  OK
- folder: 11  - OK
- folder: 111 - OK
- folder: 111 - OK
- folder: 2 - NOT OK
- folder: 12 - NOT OK
- All asynchronous downloads completed in sequence.

I think it is because when I return the promise from inside, then the for loop gets interrupted.

```
function CopySubFolders(folder, destFolder) {

    // Recursively copy each subfolder
    return folder.getFoldersAsync()
    .then(function (folderlist) {
        if (folderlist.size > 0) {
            for (var i in folderlist) {
                var replace = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;
                console.log("create folder: " + folderlist[i].name);

                return destFolder.createFolderAsync(folderlist[i].name, replace)
                .then(function (newdest) {
                   return CopySubFolders(folderlist[i], newdest);
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            return WinJS.Promise.as();
        }
    });
}


CopySubFolders(folder, self.localFolder)
.then(function () {
    completeFunc("Done");
    console.log("All asynchronous downloads completed in sequence.");
})
```

Any idea how to return the promise without interrupting the for loop?

PS: if I use a forEach loo it will not get interrupted, but then I loose the capability of returning the folders in sequence.

Example:

- folder: 1   -  OK
- All asynchronous downloads completed in sequence.
- folder: 11  - OK
- folder: 111 - OK
- folder: 111 - OK
- folder: 2 - OK
- folder: 12 - OK

Comment: sorry I added the part that gather the folderlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just like with any function, if you execute a `return` statement, the function will stop what it's doing and return. You should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do with the following:

**Edit:** if you don't need them to complete in a specific sequence, you can accomplish what you are trying to do with `WinJS.Promise.join()` (a.k.a. `Promise.all()` in other promise dialects) and `map` (I'm factoring out the inner part here to cut down on the nesting):

```
function CopySubFolders(folder, destFolder) {
    return folder.getFoldersAsync()
    .then(function (folderlist) {
        return WinJS.Promise.join(folderlist.map(function (folder) {
            return CopyFolder(folder, destFolder);
        });
    });
}

function CopyFolder(folder, destFolder) {
    var replace = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;
    console.log("create folder: " + folder.name);

    return destFolder.createFolderAsync(folder.name, replace)
           .then(function (newdest) {
                return CopySubFolders(folder, newdest);
           });
}
```

As a complete side note, please don't use `for...in` with arrays. It's a bad idea.

And as a bit of a vestige of this post, here is how you would be able to create the folders in sequence if you needed to (though that is not recommended):

```
function CopySubFolders(folder, destFolder) {
    var p = Promise.resolve();

    return folder.getFoldersAsync()
    .then(function (folderlist) {
        return folderlist.forEach(function (folder) {
            var replace = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;
            console.log("create folder: " + folder.name);

            p = p.then(function () {    
                destFolder.createFolderAsync(folder.name, replace)
                .then(function (newdest) {
                    return CopySubFolders(folder, newdest);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    return p;
}
```

Another slightly cleaner way to do the same thing, as illustrated [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), is to use `folderlist.reduce()`:

```
function CopySubFolders(folder, destFolder) {
    return folder.getFoldersAsync()
    .then(function (folderlist) {
        return folderlist.reduce(function (sequence, folder) {
            var replace = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;
            console.log("create folder: " + folder.name);

            return sequence.then(function () {    
                destFolder.createFolderAsync(folder.name, replace)
                .then(function (newdest) {
                    return CopySubFolders(folder, newdest);
                });
            });
        }, Promise.resolve());
    });
}
```

Comment: thnkas I will try this solution with reduce. I do not need them to return ordered, I just need the function to return when the last ofthe calls has been completed

Comment: how do you transklate that Promise.resolve() in WinJS? is it WinJS.Promise.as()?

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. OP: `Promise.resolve` is indeed `WinJS.Promise.as`.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark If you don't need to run them in sequence, then you don't need `Promise.resolve` or `WinJS.Promise.as`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @JLRishe So if I use the solution with reduce and just remove the Promise.resolve() it will still work (but not in sequence), right?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark No, that wouldn't work at all. I recommend the first example in my answer, which uses `WinJS.Promise.join()` and will run in parallel.

Comment: thanks It works and it made me understand a bit better how the recursiveness works together with the promises