# How to wait for AsyncRequests for each element from an array using reduce and promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm new on AngularJS and JavaScript.

I am getting remote information for each of the elements of an array (cars) and creating a new array (interested prospects). So I need to sync the requests. I need the responses of each request to be added in the new array in the same order of the cars.

I did it first in with a for:

```
for (a in cars) {
    //async request
    .then(function () {
        //update the new array
    });
}
```

This make all the requests but naturally didn't update the new array.

After seeking in forums, I found this great examples and explanations for returning a intermediate promise and sync all of them.

```
1. http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605215/return-a-promise-from-inside-a-for-loop 
 3. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/
```

(@MaurizioIndenmark, @Mark Rajcok , @Michelle Tilley, @Nolan Lawson)

I couldn't use the Promise.resolve() suggested in the second reference. So I had used `$q.defer()` and   `resolve()`. I guess I have to inject a dependency or something else that I missed. As shown below:

In the Controller I have:

```
$scope.interestedProspects = [] ;

RequestDetailsOfAsync = function ($scope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var id = carLists.map(function (car) {
        return car.id;
    }).reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue.then(function () {
            TheService.AsyncRequest(currentValue).then(function (rData) {
                $scope.interestedProspects.push(rData);
            });
        });
    }, deferred.resolve());
};
```

In the Service I have something like:

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('TheService', function ($http) {
    return {
        AsyncRequest = function (keyID) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = authorized.get("somep.provider.api/theService.json?" + keyID).done(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

The displayed error I got: `Uncaught TypeError: previousValue.then is not a function`

I made a jsfiddle reusing others available, so that it could be easier to solve this  http://jsfiddle.net/alisatest/pf31g36y/3/. How to wait for AsyncRequests for each element from an array using reduce and promises

I don't know if the mistakes are:

- the place where the resolve is placed in the controller function.
- the way the reduce function is used

The previousValue and currentValue sometimes are seen by javascript like type of Promise initially and then as a number. In the jsfiddle I have a working example of the use of the reduce and an http request for the example.

Comment: Your fiddle is not related to the question.

Comment: your fiddle does nothing with promises to reduce, so how is it related?

Comment: `I couldn't use the Promise.resolve()` - so use `$q.resolve()` rather than a deferred anti-pattern

Comment: Does `TheService.AsyncRequest(currentValue)` return a promise?

Comment: Your **Service** is not valid javascript .. `return { AsyncRequest = function() {} }` is probably meant to be `return { AsyncRequest : function() {} }` - and it **must** return a promise to be *compatible* with your Controller code

Comment: When you post code with so much nesting, do the effort to [correctly format it](http://jsbeautifier.org/). Most people won't waste time to read randomly indented code.

Comment: Is it important that you use reduce? If yes, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this pattern for what you want to do:

```
        cars.reduce(function(promise, car) {
            return promise.then(function(){
              return TheService.AsyncRequest(car).then(function (rData) {
                $scope.details.push(rData);
              });
            });
        }, $q.when());
```

This will do all the asynchronous calls for every car exactly in the sequence they are in the cars array. `$q.all` may also be sufficient if the order the async calls are made doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Yes the order matters, and is not required to use array.reduce, is that none of what I tried was working (first time using promises). By the way, do you mean that $q.all will be an alternative to q.when() in the pattern you posted that wont allocate the responses in order?

Comment: No, $q.all is a different way of working with multiple asynch calls that return promises. Glad I could help. Please accept this answer to help other who may have the same question.

Comment: If I want to get the instance of the Promise that syncs the async requests, for unnesting the code. How should I do? And sendondly, is there a way to simplify the code with the same requirements? If so, how?

Comment: Additionally, I need help again, is that I try to access the information inside then and it logs an error promise  Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. Because I want to replace some characters.

Comment: As this is off topic regarding the original question you should maybe ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling `reduce` on an array of ids, but assume in the passed function that you are dealing with promises.

In general, when you want to sync a set of promises, you can use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

You pass an array of promises and get another promise in return that will be resolved with an array of results.