# Get started with promises, how to simplify them, control start, access to responses, wait multiple async requests in order?

Tags: asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

Getting started to promises, some general questions:

1. Should callbacks be always nested in the same block of the code? How could promises be written in a simple way?
2. If multiple functions are called inside the then part of a promise, why it is always undefined in the console? Why is the code executed if the promise is not done? Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. (Being undefined the rData of an async response)?
3. Is it possible to name an instance of a promise so that when it really finishes, data can be accessed?
4. Is there a way to know which promises haven't finished?
5. Can promises share callback functions?
6. At what part of the following code could be the variable for the instance of the promise that syncs multiple async requests, for unnesting the code.
7. Which are other ways to write the same functionality of the code? In particular to simply it?
8. How could be written a variant of the code to control the start of the requests so that they start sequencially? I read about using an angular.factory but wasn't very clear about. -->

> Is it possible to control the start and end of promises in AngularJS?
>   How? In the case of having multiple of the same type to start, and
>   when some have dependencies of data between them?

Based on the following code as part of a controller at AngularJS from a previous issue ([How to wait for AsyncRequests for each element from an array using reduce and promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115441/how-to-wait-for-asyncrequests-for-each-element-from-an-array-using-reduce-and-pr)):

```
$scope.details = [] ;

var carList = [
    {
        id: 0,
        brand: 'Nissan',
        status: 'В резерве',
        mileage: 0,
        price: 20000
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        brand: 'Mazda',
        status: 'На складе',
        mileage: 0,
        price: 30000
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        brand: 'BMW',
        status: 'На складе',
        mileage: 12000,
        price: 35000
    }
];


        cars.reduce(function(promise, car) {
            return promise.then(function(){
              return TheService.AsyncRequest(car).then(function (rData) {
                (String(rData)).replace ("abd", "abc");
                validateData (rData );
                decirateData (rData );
                $scope.details.push(rData);
              });
            });
        }, $q.when());
```

In the case of $q, and Promise?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're requesting and why? Perhaps with a specific use case and/or code/pseudocode?

Comment: FYI - a: `(String(rData)).replace("abd", "abc");` has no effect ... b: you're nesting promises when you don't need to ... and your point **8** ... this wont start the next `car` until the previous `car` has completed, so yeah, it's possible to perform the requests sequentially, your code does just that

Comment: Voting to close as 10 questions asked in one.

Comment: @Bejanmin Gruenbaum If you are a busy collegue, and I need help what is that kind of help? Do you enjoy being rude? Why I can't ask? Hard day?

Comment: I'll figure out how to report the issue! Meanwhile, I hope others with high reputation agree with me to reduce yours!!!! Voting for giving you an advertise for being rude!